# How can one compute directly the dimension of $\Lambda^k (V)$ from this definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, and
$$\Lambda (V):=(T V)/I$$
be one of the usual (well-known) definitions of the exterior algebra. I am struggling on proving directly that $\{e_I\}$, where $I$ is any multi-index of increasing $k$ indices is a basis of $\Lambda ^k V$ as a vector space, where $\Lambda ^k V$ is by definition the vector space spanned by $\{e_J\}$, $J$ being any multi-index of $k$ indices. Every proof of this fact that I've seen is by the definition as multilinear alternating maps, and relies on taking dual bases etc, and I can't adapt it to this case.

Comment: Spivak has a proof of this in his book Calculus on Manifolds. *Any* alternating $k$-multilinear form can be written to look like $$\omega =\sum \lambda_I e_I$$ where $I=i_1<\cdots <i_k$, and $e_I$ is the product $e_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{i_k}$. Thus $\wedge^k(V)$ has dimension at most $\binom nk$, $n=\dim V$. It suffices one shows the $e_I$ as defined above are linearly independent. One can do this by evaluating at appropriate vectors, just like in the case of $V^{\otimes k}$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff That is the issue. That the set generates is by definition, but when you talk about "evaluating at appropriate vectors", you are talking about the definition of $\Lambda^k(V)$ by multilinear maps, which is not the one I'm mentioning.

Comment: Ah, I see. One can still give a proof, by taking a basis of $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be a basis for $V$. I claim that $e_{i_1}\cdots e_{i_k}$ with $i_1<\cdots < i_k$ is a basis for $\wedge^k (V)$. Indeed, suppose that a sum $$\sum \lambda_I e_I=0$$
let $J$ be the unique subset of $[n]$ such that $I\cap J=\varnothing$ and $I\cup J=[n]$. Then taking the product with $e_J$ gives $$\lambda_I e_I\wedge e_J=0$$

so $\lambda_I=0$. Indeed, since $I$ is different from all the other $I'$, then $J$ must intersect $I'$ and $e_I'e_J=0$. As an example, consider $\lambda x y+\mu y z=0$, in $\wedge(x,y,z)$. Then taking the product with $x$ gives $\mu xyz=0$.